# iPhone: View loading but not view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I had an issue with a project getting the dreaded "Error: cannot attach to process ID 0". Tried everything I could and it wanted nothing to do with me. So I started a new project and readded all my files and frameworks and what not in it.

Now my project runs. It shows me the first screen in my storyboard. However, the ViewController class attached to the window is not getting loaded and neither is the NavController class attached to my navigation controller. I reset the class in the Identity Inspector but still it wants nothing to do with me.

I added some NSLog(@"Test"); in the viewDidLoad methods of both my classes and they're not getting called. However, I added that same line to the AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLoadingWithOptions and that one did pop up in the debugger.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please put a picture of Storyboard. For the first problem (cannot attach), a restart of the Mac is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met that issue before, maybe it is some bugs of Xcode, the following steps works for me:

- quit simulator
- clean project
- delete project's derived data
- quit Xcode
- restart Mac if you like

then reopen Xcode and everything is ok.

Comment: I did all this. Then tried again. Didn't work. So escaped out of the app in the iPhone simulator, deleted the app from the phone and rebuilded et voila! Worked. You can still get the checkmark.